# Excel with two different sheet, I need to reorder them

Tags: excel

Let's say that we have two different excel sheets. For example, on sheet #1, "A1", there is a name "Joe" and "B1" is his 2021 salary of $ 35,000; and on sheet #2, there is also a name "Joe" in the "A" column, his 2022 salary is at B column,  but we don't know which rows it is. I want to put the 2022 salary on sheet #1, C1. There are many of those cells(name and salary) that are not Arranged. I want to match each of them and have 3 columns(name, 2021 salary, 2022 salary).  I don't know how to do it. Any ideas?
Thank you !!!

Comment: attach a sample file

Comment: Try index() with match(). Lits of examples on here that you can look at since you don’t offer any data.

Comment: I am not able to attch a file, but I have the data links.. the file name is "2022 Student Research Case Study Challenge Player Data", From  https://www.soa.org/research/opportunities/2022-student-research-case-study-challenge/.